# Problem with Taylor Series

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion, approximation

So, I'm studying a book and got stuck in the following lines:
[image]

What should I do/use to get from the first line to the second one?
How can I perform that kind of approximation?

I was thinking in this way: If I treat everything within the square brackets as $f(x)$, and I know its Taylor series, is there a way to get the Taylor series of $\frac{1}{f(x)}$?

Comment: Does this help? https://mathworld.wolfram.com/NegativeBinomialSeries.html

Comment: @Tavish yeah! Tks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:

Use $ [{1-x}]^{-1}=1+x+ {x^2}+\dots$

with $x=(t_0-t)H_0+\frac12(t_0-t)^2q_0H_0^2+\dots$

Comment: Hi, would it be possible if you can help with some graph theory problems? Like in a room chat or something? I just have many problems, and instead of posting for each on stackoverflow, and you answer regardless here, I thought you may help this way, as I checked the users and found you good at discrete mathematics,